# firebaseui with angular determine login state on revisit

Tags: typescript, firebase, firebase-authentication, firebaseui

I am using firebaseUI to login using facebook. My app.components.html has two divs one to show firebaseui tag and another to show after user is logged in.

My question is when i have logged in once then how do i determine that i have already logged in? The code looks like be

```
constructor(private afAuth: AngularFireAuth,
            private core:CoreService) {
  }

  successCallback(data: FirebaseUISignInSuccessWithAuthResult) {
    console.log('successCallback', data);
    this.core.loggedIn = true
  }


  logout() {
    this.core.loggedIn = false
    this.afAuth.auth.signOut();
  }

  errorCallback(data: FirebaseUISignInFailure) {
    alert('Failed to login')
    this.core.loggedIn = false
    console.warn('errorCallback', data);
  }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.afAuth.authState.subscribe(d => {console.log('subscribed to firebase auth' + JSON.stringify(d))});
  }
}
```

So when i revisit the successCallback is not called as there is no login clicked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you reload the page, the user's authentication state should be restored automatically and your `authState` subscriber will be called:

```
this.afAuth.authState.subscribe(d => {
  console.log('subscribed to firebase auth' + JSON.stringify(d))
});
```

Comment: ok just wanted to be sure that this is a safe to assume i am logged in again. any specific value should i check or just checking d is not null is sufficient to say i am logged in?

Comment: If the user is signed in, `d` has a value. If the user is not signed in, `d` won't have a value. Also see https://angularfirebase.com/snippets/angularfire2-version-4-authentication-service/